# CakePHP - Manage multiple file upload fields and handle them correctly

Tags: cakephp, upload

i've been bothering and looking for a solution for quite a while now.

I'm planning an offer database for holidays with CakePHP. Data relations work fine to this point. Now i've got a mask "Add Offer" where it should be possible to upload several images in different fields, for example there are those fields available :

```
Name: 
Location:
Image 1:
Image 2:
Image 3:
Image 4:
```

How would i handle a file upload for each field provided and insert it back in the correct field into the database? I've thought about a multiple upload field but the customer doesn't want it that way. Is there a possible solution with a switch case?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just create multiple fields like the client ask.

But store them in `$this->data` as an array but doing the following.

```
echo $this->Form->input('image.' , array('type' => 'file' , 'label' => 'image 1'));
echo $this->Form->input('image.' , array('type' => 'file' , 'label' => 'image 2'));
```

Do not forget the dot after image

Now when you `pr($this->data)` you will get something like the following

```
Model => {
image => { 
[1] =>{image info error etc}
[2] =>{image info error etc}
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And how would i store them in the right fields in my database. I'm not too fit in cakephp so its a hard time for me to understand :( can you provide an example?

Comment: Assuming you have a correctly built database. You should run a loop on `$this->data['model']['image']` and for each image you would upload it, then you would store in a separate table in the database with the link to it, you will also store a foreign key in that row pointing to the owner of that image. Let me know if you want to know how to design a proper database. Tho you should ask it in a separate question or make some more research about it.

Comment: Use '$this->Form->input('Model.0.field', array('type'=>'file');'